# VueJS: API proxying with variables in URL possible?

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js

I'm using API proxying

```
'/api/visitor': {
    target: 'http://test.mydomain.com/api/visitor',
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
        "^/api/visitor": ""
    }
},
```

This works perfectly. the problem here is, is that I also have a couple of API's that have, for example an ID, in the url. for example:

```
http://test.mydomain.com/api/{id}/lead
```

Is the `{id}` is thus dynamic. How do I still proxy this?

Any thoughts?

Comment: why not proxy the whole `/api`?

Comment: @pranavjindal999 is right here

Comment: So I need to proxy only `/api` and then I can still use `/api/visitor` as the `url` in `axios`